# `ggalluvial`: `geom_flow` fill color from destination stratum

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram, ggalluvial

I have the following example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)
data <- tibble(id = paste0("S", 1:20), 
       class_1 = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
       class_2 = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8), rep("A", 4)))
data_pvt <- data %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with("class"), names_to = "class_type", values_to = "class_label") %>%
    mutate(class_type = factor(class_type),
           class_label = factor(class_label))
ggplot(data_pvt, aes(x = fct_rev(class_type), stratum = class_label, alluvium = id,
                     label = class_label)) +
    geom_flow(aes(fill = class_label), stat = "alluvium", 
              lode.guidance = "frontback") +
    geom_stratum(aes(fill = class_label)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1, 0)) +
    labs(x = "Class system", y = "n") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I would like `geom_flow` to take the `fill` color from the top stratum (`class_1`) instead of the bottom stratum (`class_2`). I could achieve this by not `fct_rev(class_type)` at the beginning, but then `class_1` is at the bottom, while I want it at the top.

Any ideas? I could use other functions from `ggalluvium` or `ggforce`, but I'd like to keep the option of having the stratum colored by `class_label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `aes.flow = "backward"`?

```r
ggplot(data_pvt, aes(x = fct_rev(class_type), stratum = class_label, alluvium = id,
                     label = class_label)) +
    geom_flow(aes(fill = class_label), stat = "alluvium", 
              lode.guidance = "frontback", aes.flow = "backward") +
    geom_stratum(aes(fill = class_label)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1, 0)) +
    labs(x = "Class system", y = "n") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]